# Getting Oracle error 12538 when running exe from another app

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

I have a console application that runs fine when launched directly. However, if I launch the application from a .NET app I get error 12538 which seems to be a protocol error.

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(executable, args);
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = startInfo;
p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
p.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(OnDataReceived);
p.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(OnErrorReceived);
p.Exited += new EventHandler(OnProcessExit);
p.Start();
p.BeginOutputReadLine();
p.BeginErrorReadLine();
p.WaitForExit();
```

Any idea what would cause this? The .NET app does use 64 bit Oracle when the console app uses 32 bit but I wouldn't think this would matter since they're not in the same memory space (or at least shouldn't be)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 64/32 bit difference should affect things, as long as you've got both Oracle drivers installed. I would guess that either the connection string for the console app is wrong, or the 32 bit driver is set up incorrectly - different TNSNames file from the 64 bit one for instance.

[This](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_iora_12538_tns_no_protocol_adapter.htm) is a reasonable description of the error.

Comment: The console app works fine called directly so I wouldn't be a problem with the driver.
I set TNS_ADMIN prior to calling the console app from another app. I tell it to use the same tnsnames file that the .net application uses.
The params being used by the console app is the same in both cases

Comment: Might be an idea to check the Environment variables in the console app?

Comment: Turned out ORACLE_HOME and TNS_ADMIN were being set by the .net application. I removed both of them from the env vars prior to calling the console app and it fixed the problem. Thanks for your help.